# Verilog `define macro delimiter

Tags: fpga, verilog

How does Verilog distinguish between the **name** and **text** when using the `define` macro?

```
`define name text
```

For instance, this is a valid define statement:

```
`define zero 16'b0
```

But is the following valid? The desired **text** is `{ WORD_SIZE { 1'b0 } }`:

```
`define zero { WORD_SIZE { 1'b0 } }
```

If Verilog uses spaces to distinguish between the name and text, is there something I can wrap the text with so that I can have spaces inside the text as seen in the second example?

Comment: DId you try it and it didn't work? I'd guess the first token after `\`define` is the name and everything after it on a line is the text (assuming no arguments for the macro). I found examples online that show spaces in the text, so I'd expect it to just work.

Comment: why are you asking? .... have you received an error?

Comment: I was able to try it out. No errors were raised. I was overthinking it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Verilog Standard does not impose a restriction on usage of whitespace characters. Quoting from the [LRM](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1620780):

> The macro text can be any arbitrary text specified on the same line as
>   the text macro name. If more than one line is necessary to specify the
>   text, the newline shall be preceded by a backslash (\). The first
>   newline not preceded by a backslash shall end the macro text...

Comment: Hi could you please add a link to the document quoted, would love to look at it.

Comment: Please find the reference [IEEE Std 1364™-2005](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1620780)